# how to save image url into session

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to save a image url into session and this url I get into another page load then load into image button. Is it possible or not? I use the following  code to save image url;

```
Image = Image1.ImageUrl.ToString();
                        Session["logo"] = Convert.FromBase64String(Image);
```

But I get the following error, like so;

`The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.`

Another page I get this image url,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    Image img =(Image)Session["logo"];
    ImageButton1.Controls.Add(img);
}
```

The above code also gets an error. So please help me.

Comment: What part of the first error don't you understand? What does the second error say?

Comment: Can't you just store it as a plain string? `Session["Logo"] = Image1.ImageUrl.ToString()`

Comment: A bit of confusion here? Save a string and restore an Image?

Comment: post the real code where you had problem

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the URL or the binary data of the image?  You are storing the URL (e.g. `http://www.mycompany.com/logo.png`) in the `Image` variable, but then trying to "decode" it from Base64.  It looks like you're trying to get the binary data of the image and store *that* in session.  Why not just store the URL as-is rather than trying to decode it?

```
string image = Image1.ImageUrl.ToString();
Session["logo"] = image;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string imgURL = Session["logo"];
    ImageButton1.Controls.Add(new Image() { ImageURL = imgURL });
}
```

Otherwise you're going to have to create an `HttpRequest` to capture the binary data of the image, then embed that in the form (which is not as simple as adding an image control since there's nowhere to but the binary data in the web control)